# Comparing list items and tuples

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

In Python 3, I'm trying to create a program which takes input from a user as 3 digit codes and converts them into items in a list. It then compares these items with the first(the 3 digit code) part of a tuple in a list of tuples and prints the **whole** tuple.

```
import shares
portfolio_str=input("Please list portfolio: ")
portfolio_str= portfolio_str.replace(' ','')
portfolio_str= portfolio_str.upper()
portfolio_list= portfolio_str.split(',')
print(portfolio_list)
print()
print('{:<6} {:<20} {:>8}'.format('Code', 'Name', 'Price'))
data=shares.EXCHANGE_DATA
for  (code, name, share_value) in data:
      if code == i in portfolio_list:
        print('{:<6} {:<20} {:>8.2f}'.format(code, name, share_value))
else:
        print("Failure")
```

As you can see I'm using a module called shares containing a list of tuples called EXCHANGE_DATA which is set out like this:

```
EXCHANGE_DATA = [('AIA', 'Auckair', 1.50),
         ('AIR', 'Airnz', 5.60),
         ('AMP', 'Amp',3.22), 
         ('ANZ', 'Anzbankgrp', 26.25),
         ('ARG', 'Argosy', 12.22),
         ('CEN', 'Contact', 11.22),
         ('CNU', 'Chorus',3.01),
         ('DIL', 'Diligent', 5.3),
         ('DNZ', 'Dnz Property', 2.33),
         ('EBO', 'Ebos', 1.1),
```

An exemplar input would be:
`AIA, AMP, ANZ`

The corresponding output would be:

```
Code         Name         Price
AIA          Auckair      1.50
AMP          Amp          3.22
ANZ          Anzbankgrp   26.25
```

I'm just stuck on the for and/or if statements which I think I need.

Comment: Looks like you are using the wrong data structure - you want a dict.

Comment: @Lattyware I would like to use a dictionary but I'm stuck using a list of tuples for this (it's a set question using given data etc.)....

Comment: `data_dict = {code: (name, price) for code, name, price in EXCHANGE_DATA}` - Easy enough to convert it with a [dict comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw), and then it'll simplify down the other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is this here:

```
if code == i in portfolio_list:
```

This doesn't make sense in Python. `in` checks if a given value is contained in the list, so this checks if `i` is in `portfolio_list`, then checks if `code` is equal to `True` or `False` (whatever `i in portfolio_list` returned. What you want is simply:

```
if code in portfolio_list:
```

Note that if `portfolio_list` could be long, it might be worth making it a set, as checking for membership in a set is significantly more efficient for large amounts of data.

Your syntax appears to be a mashup of different methodologies. You might have meant:

```
if any(code == i for i in portfolio_list):
```

However, as this is directly equivalent to `code in portfolio_list`, but more verbose and inefficient, it's not a good solution.